# How do I declare a function to be used as a function pointer in c?

Tags: c

I am confused with function pointer declaration.

I have an api `abc()` which takes an argument as so:

```
void abc(void (*my_func)(void *p), int, int)
```

If I want to pass my function as an argument to that api, I am declaring it in my .h file:

```
void (*xyz)(void *p)
```

and defining as:

```
void *(xyz)(void *p){
statements;
}
```

but this throws an error. Please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

you just need to declare it:

```
void xyz(void *p);
```

with the implementation the same way.

When you pass it into your api, the type system figures out it out automatically:

```
abc(xyz,someint,anotherint);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `(*xyz)` means that it is a function pointer.

Function pointers are best handled with `typedef`s. So it is guaranteed that there is nothing wrong.

I would do the following:

```
// define a type for the function (not its pointers, as you can often read)
typedef void my_func_t(void *p);

void abc(my_func_t*, int, int);

// declaration in order to be type-safe - impossible if only the pointer would be typedef'd
my_func_t my_func_impl; 

// definition:
void my_func_impl(void *p)
{
    do_something_with(p);
}
```

and then you can call your `abc()` with `abc(my_func_impl, 47, 11)`. You can put a `&` before `my_func_impl` there in order to point out that it is the function address you wish to obtain, but it is optional.

An alternative would be to write

```
typedef void (*my_func_p)(void *p);
```

and use `my_func_p` instead of `my_func_t *`, but this has the disadvantage that you cannot write `my_func_t my_func_impl;`.

Why would you want to do that?

Well, if, by any coincidence or accident, the function definition **or** the typedef is changed, they won't match any longer, but the collision is not declared as error, but only as warning (Mismatch pointer). OTOH, `my_func_t my_func_impl;` serves as a kind of prototype, which causes a function header mismatch, which is an error.

Comment: I've seen it far more often as `typedef void (*my_func_ptr)(void *);`.

Comment: Yes, I too. But then this trick with `my_func_t my_func_impl;` isn't possible any longer. I'll edit.

Comment: No offense, but many programmers, including myself, will look at `my_func_t my_func_impl;` and think it's a global variable, and probably a function pointer. It's a good example of writing for the computer and not the programmer. Tricks like this resulted in the [severe restrictions on `typedef` in the Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) (Chapter 5, "Typedefs").

Comment: It is neither a pointer nor a struct, and I thinks it fits into "Maybe there are other cases too" (YMMV!). In any case, it helps to avoid mistakes. Maybe the use should be clarified with comments in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want `xyz` to be the function that is passed to `abc`, right?

As the argument `my_func` indicates, you have a pointer to a function that takes `void *` as argument and returns `void`

```
 type (*func_pointer)(type, type, type, .......)
   ^   ^       ^        ^     ^     ^
   |   |       |        |     |     |
   |   |       |        argument types
   |   |   pointer name
   | This is a function pointer
return type
```

Therefore, you need to declare `xyz` as:

```
void xyz(void *p);
```

And the same in implementation:

```
void xyz(void *p){
    statements;
}
```

What you are doing wrong is that, the line you wrote in the .h file defines a function pointer, named `xyz`. The function pointer has no value, because you never wrote `xyz = some_function;`

What you have written in the source file is a function, also with name `xyz` that takes a `void *` as input and returns a `void *`, instead of `void` which was your intention.

Maybe this helps you get less confused:

When you write `int *x;`, `x` is a pointer to `int`. Then you can have `int y;` that doesn't have an extra `*` and write `x = &y;`.

It's the same with functions. If you have `void (*funcptr)(void *p);`, then all you need is a function that says `void some_func(void *p){}` (again without the extra `*`) and write `funcptr = some_func;`. You don't need the `&` since function names are in fact pointer to the function. You could put it to be more explicit though.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It clearly explains the root cause of this problem. Very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare and define your function as you would any other:

```
void xyz(void *p);

void xyz(void *p){
    // ...
}
```

and pass a pointer to the API:

```
abc(xyz, 42, 7);
```

Function names are automatically interpreted as function pointers where appropriate. You can also explicitly take the address of the function, if brevity isn't your thing:

```
abc(&xyz, 42, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of 'abc' is the pointer of function returning 'void' and having 'void *' as an argument...

So your code should look like:

```
void
myFunc (void *) 
{
   // ... my statements
}

...

abc (myFunc, 10, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
void abc(void* (*my_func)(void*), int a, int b) {
    my_func(0);
}

void *(xyz)(void *p) {}

int main() {
    abc(xyz, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

When you write `void (*my_func)(void *p)` it means pointer to function, that returns void
And `void (*my_func)(void *p)` it means pointer to function, that returns pointer